# Compiling multiple Typescript Files in Parallel

Tags: typescript

We have a really great set of Typescript files in our solution and this is still growing and I was thinking if there is a way we could compile the Typescript files in parallel. If possible I am not sure on how it will resolve the dependencies… Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

> and I was thinking if there is a way we could compile the Typescript files in parallel.

If you are not using `--out` then you can compile *just the changed `js` file*. It takes under a second. And then on deployment you can do a full compile … which will take around 5 seconds (still pretty fast compared to most legacy workflows).